# Transform a generic JS collection to an object with specific keys and grouped values

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, collections, grouping

I would like to create a JS function that transform a generic collection (an array or object of nested levels of arrays or objects) into an object that his keys are an input array argument (if provided, if not all distinct objects keys in input) and values are an array of leaf values for these keys in input). Leaf values can be distinct if flag provided.

Something like:

```
transform([{a:1, b:'1', c:true, d:1},{a:'1', b:2, c:3, d:false}, {a:1, c:'test'}], ['a','b','c'], true);
```

OR

```
transform({x:{b:2,c:{c:3, d:1}},b:'1',z:{b:2,c:true,a:1},a:'1',g:{c:'test',d:false}}, ['a','b','c'], true);
```

Will produce the same output:

```
{a:[1, '1'], b:['1', 2], c:[true, 3, 'test']}
```

- First argument is the collection - mandatory
- Second one is array of keys - optional
- Third argument is the unique flag - optional

If second argument is omitted. It will produce this :

```
{a:[1, '1'], b:['1', 2], c:[true, 3, 'test'], d:[1,false]}
```

What is the fast and/or elegant way to do it?

Is there any lodash/underscore helper for it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

### The basics

The main part of this problem is walking the object trees recursively and collecting the values.

To do so, we write a function that looks at a value and determines if it's an object. If it isn't, we concatenate the value to a results array. If it is, we reduce its values using the same logic.

```js
const deepValues = (obj, res = []) => 
  isObject(obj)
    ? Object.values(obj).reduce(flip(deepValues), res)
    : res.concat(obj)
     
console.log(
  deepValues({x:{b:2,c:{c:3, d:1}}})
);
  
// Utils
function flip(f) { return (x, y) => f(y, x) };
function isObject(x) { return Object.prototype.toString.call(x) === "[object Object]" };
```

### Customizing it

Once you understand this function, adding the other bits and pieces makes a bit more sense.

#### Step 1: Not *all* the values...

So we want to concatenate the value to the results if its key matches our criterium.

We add a `keyPred` function to our signature and start working with `[key, value]` pairs rather than just the values. The predicate takes a key and returns a boolean that indicates if we should store it.

The function becomes a bit harder to read, but it's not that big of a difference from the initial one:

```js
const certainDeepValues = (keyPred, obj, res = []) =>
  Object.entries(obj)
        .reduce((r, [k, v]) => 
          isObject(v) 
            ? certainDeepValues(keyPred, v, r)
            : keyPred(k) ? r.concat(v) : r
        , res);

console.log(
  certainDeepValues(
    k => k === "c",
    {x:{b:2,c:{c:3, d:1}}}
  )
);

// Utils
function isObject(x) { return Object.prototype.toString.call(x) === "[object Object]" };
```

#### Step 2: Only collect unique values

Javascript has the perfect type for a collection of unique values: a `Set`, which makes this a small change. The default argument is `new Set` and the `concat` method becomes `add`.

```js
const certainDeepValues = (keyPred, obj, res = new Set()) =>
  Object.entries(obj)
        .reduce((r, [k, v]) => 
          isObject(v) 
            ? certainDeepValues(keyPred, v, r)
            : keyPred(k) ? r.add(v) : r
        , res);

console.log(
  [...certainDeepValues(
    k => k === "c",
    {x:{b:2,c:{c:3, d:1, e: { c: "2" }}}, c: 3}
  )]
);

// Utils
function flip(f) { return (x, y) => f(y, x) };
function isObject(x) { return Object.prototype.toString.call(x) === "[object Object]" };
```

### Your own signature

Now, all there's left is to implement the desired signature. This is where it gets a bit ugly, but since you didn't post any attempts and merely wrote your "question" as an assignment to us, I'll leave it up to you to clean it up :)

```js
const certainDeepValues = 
  (concat, keyPred, obj, res = new Set()) =>
    Object.entries(obj)
          .reduce((r, [k, v]) => 
            isObject(v) 
              ? certainDeepValues(concat, keyPred, v, r)
              : keyPred(k) ? concat(r, k, v) : r
          , res);

const transform = (xs = [], keys = [], uniquesOnly = false) => {
  const keySet = new Set(keys);
  const keyPred = keys.length
    ? k => keySet.has(k)
    : k => true;
    
  const concat = uniquesOnly 
    ? (acc, k, v) => (acc[k] = (acc[k] || new Set()).add(v), acc)
    : (acc, k, v) => (acc[k] = (acc[k] || []).concat(v), acc)

  const unwrap = uniquesOnly
    ? acc => mapObj(s => [...s], acc)
    : acc => acc;
    
  return unwrap(xs.reduce(
    (r, x) => certainDeepValues(concat, keyPred, x, r),
    {}
  ));
};

console.log(
  JSON.stringify(
    transform([{a:1, b:'1', c:true, d:1},{a:'1', b:2, c:3, d:false}, {a:1, c:'test'}], ['a','b','c'], true)
  )
);
console.log(
  JSON.stringify(
    transform([{x:{b:2,c:{c:3, d:1}},b:'1',z:{b:2,c:true,a:1},a:'1',g:{c:'test',d:false}}], ['a','b','c'], true)
  )
);
console.log(
  JSON.stringify(
    transform([{x:{b:2,c:{c:3, d:1}},b:'1',z:{b:2,c:true,a:1},a:'1',g:{c:'test',d:false}}], undefined, true)
  )
);


// Utils
function mapObj(f, obj) { return Object.assign({}, ...Object.entries(obj).map(([k, v]) => ({[k]: f(v)}))); }
function flip(f) { return (x, y) => f(y, x) };
function isObject(x) { return Object.prototype.toString.call(x) === "[object Object]" };
```